# Draw circle with 100 points

Tags: matlab

I have to draw a circle using only `100` points. The center's coordinates are like `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,2)` etc. The circle should be inscribed within `0.6×0.6` square. I figured out I can use something like:

```
th= linspace(0,2*pi)
```

to get 100 points, and

```
x = cos(th) 
y = sin(th)
```

to get `x` and `y` coordinates to be used in `plot(x,y)`.

However, I do not know how to get the exact coordinates or `0.6×0.6` square. If there was not np requirement of exactly `100` points I could use `circleplot` syntax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this (for each circle):

```
th = linspace(0, 2*pi);
x = sin(th) * .3 + cX;
y = cos(th) * .3 + cY;
plot(x,y);
```

where **cX** and **cY** are the center of the circle.

Comment: Close but not quite. The center of the circles should be at those coordinates. Like (1,1), (1,2), (2,2). Thanks though!

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope! It fixes the center but the area of circle increases.

Comment: `th` should really be `th=linspace(1,2*pi,101);th=th(1:end-1)` so that you don't get `th=0` and `th=2*pi` on top of each other, and get 100 distinct points. Unless I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Actually told it wrong in the comment last time. Your code is alright. Sorry about that. My bad. Thanks!